# JPA @JoinColumns Unable to find column with logical name

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I Have a Spring Boot Project. Nothing but 3 clases (entities), when i try to run the project i get the error " Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name:"

These are the classes:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="HOL")
public class Holding  implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1110819289093936782L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID_HOL")
    private Long idHolding;


    @Column(name="NOMBRE_HOLDING", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String nombre;

}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="HOL_JURI", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "ID_HOL_JURI", "ID_HOL"})})
public class HoldingJurisdiccion implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3441056203408582532L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID_HOL_JURI")
    private Long idHoldingJurisdiccion;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_HOL")
    private Holding holding;
    
    @Column(name="NOMBRE", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String nombreHoldingJuridiccion;

    
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="ENTIDAD")
public class Entidad  implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1038561346897695629L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID_ENTIDAD")
    private Long idEntidad;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_HOL_JURI", referencedColumnName = "ID_HOL_JURI"),
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_HOL", referencedColumnName="ID_HOL")
    })
    private HoldingJurisdiccion holdingJurisdiccion;    

}
```

I expected the project to run, but instead got the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: ID_HOL in hol_juri
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at com.example.springBootTest.SpringBootTestApplication.main(SpringBootTestApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: ID_HOL in hol_juri
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:865) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1750) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1694) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

I tried to add backticks (´) to the referenced column name, I also tried to put the property spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true in application.properties, but still getting the same error

Comment: I suspect it is your Entidad  holdingJurisdiccion relationship. If ID_HOL_JURI really is the ID column for HOL_JURI, that means it alone uniquely identifies a HoldingJurisdiccion instance - you have no need to define foriegn keys using ID_HOL_JURI AND ID_HOL in Entidad - ID_HOL is unneccessarily redundant and should be removed. JPA providers can map fks to non-id fields, but it isn't part of the spec, and in this case it might be a problem because there is no basic mapping holding the ID_HOL value in the instance for it to use - just a guess though. You are better off with only the single FK

Comment: oh i forgot to add , uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "ID_HOL_JURI", "ID_HOL"})}) to "HOL_JURI"; the client wants the column ID_HOL en the table "ENTIDAD"

Comment: @MiguelArias Can you update your question and include the database schema?  The error is indicating that it cannot find the column in the table.

Comment: If the client wants that field for some reason, you should push back an ask why - I would suspect they will eventually want to filter using that value, and will then be stuck with the potential performance issues of only being able to access that value through joining across multiple entities (and so table joins) instead of just having it mapped as a basic column. Ie Select e from Entidad e where e.holdingJurisdiccion.holding.idHolding=:someValue vs just Select e from Entidad e where e.holdingId = someValue. Regardless, that join column is the source of your issue - remove it to confirm

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make it work.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="HOL")
public class Holding  implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1110819289093936782L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID_HOL")
    private Long idHolding;


    @Column(name="NOMBRE_HOLDING", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String nombre;

}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="HOL_JURI", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "ID_HOL_JURI", "ID_HOL"})})
public class HoldingJurisdiccion implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3441056203408582532L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID_HOL_JURI")
    private Long idHoldingJurisdiccion;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_HOL")
    private Holding holding;
    
    @Column(name="NOMBRE", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String nombreHoldingJuridiccion;

    
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="ENTIDAD")
public class Entidad  implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1038561346897695629L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID_ENTIDAD")
    private Long idEntidad;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_HOL_JURI", referencedColumnName = "ID_HOL_JURI")
    private HoldingJurisdiccion holdingJurisdiccion;    

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_HOL")
    private Holding holding;

}
```